# Can't Install IBM Data Stage Version 11.7.1.4 Client

Tags: installation, datastage

I'm trying to install IBM Data Stage Client version 11.7.1.4 using the package named IBM InfoSphere Information Server Version 11.7.1.4 on Windows 10.
BTW, it is stuck in the below step after starting the installation engine.

[image]

I checked out the requirements while trying the installation for many times.

1. Started setup.exe -force by Administrator right
2. When the default browser is Internet Explorer, the security enabled TLS 1.1 and 1.2
   => But, it shows "Not secure" flag on IE. (Chrome and Firefox too)
3. User Account Control (UAC) are off.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to determine if the installation is hung, or some other issue by checking the install log. The default location for install logs is

%TEMP%\ibm_is_logs

For example, on my Windows Client Tier, the install logs are here:

C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ibm_is_logs